# Docker container that depends on file in other container

Tags: docker, containers, docker-compose

I have monolithic application that i am trying to containerize.  The foler structure is like this:

```
--app
  |
  |-file.py <-has a variable foo that is passed in

--configs
  |
  |-variables.py <- contains foo variable
```

Right now, I have the app in a container and the configs in a container.  When I try to start up the app container, it fails because a dependency on the config container variable.

What am i doing wrong? And how should I approach this issue.  Should the app and config be in one big container for now?

I was thinking docker-compose could solve this issue. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables.py file could be (in) a volume accessed by the `app` container that you import from the `config` container with `--volumes-from config` option to `docker run`.  With Docker Compose you would use the `volumes_from` directive.

Answer (score -1):

Less recommended way -

1. Run the Config Container first, it will have its own `docker.sock`.
2. You can mount the above Docker Socket in first app Container via `-v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"`, which will let the App container access the Config container, but I think this will need privileged access.
3. This is similar to Docker in Docker concept.

You can also consider design changes to your application by serving that foo variable over HTTP, which will result in much simpler solution. You can use simple web server and urllib3 module in Python to have a simple solution which will serve the variable via Internal Docker Networking.

Comment: Mounting the Docker socket is asking for trouble.  In the case of a breach, anyone can mess with other containers and the host itself.

Comment: @RicardoBranco - Yes, that is the accepted risk when one runs container under Privileges. That's why I mentioned that it is not a recommended way, however if someone wants to use it in private environment, its about the functionality-risk trade-off.